# $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R \setminus \left\{0 \right\}, (a,b) \iff \exists k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{a}{b}=2^k.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb R \setminus \left\{0 \right\}, (a,b) \iff \exists k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{a}{b}=2^k.$

$1.$ Find the cardinality of each equivalence class.

$2.$ Find the cardinality of the equivalence classes.

**My solution :**

$1.$ $\frac{a}{b} = 2^k \implies a=2^k\cdot b.$

Define :

$$f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$$
$$f(a,k)=b \in \mathbb R \text{ such that } a=2^k\cdot b$$

Each $[a]$ equivalence class cardinality is $\aleph_0.$

$2.$ $x:=$ cardinality of the equivalence classes.

Since each equivalence class is $\aleph_0$ and $\mathbb |\mathbb R|=\mathfrak c \implies \mathfrak c=|\mathbb R|=x\cdot \aleph_0 \implies x=\mathfrak c. $

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: What is $g_a{}$?

Comment: Fix it , hope now its clear